# npm uninstall ができない

Tags: node.js, npm

首題の通りです。
`npm uninstall <package>`
をしても、アンインストール出来ない問題を抱えています。

具体的には、次のことをやろうとしています。
`npm uninstall openzeppelin-solidity@2.3.0`

[image: npm uninstallが機能してくれません]

```
$ node -v
v19.6.1
$ npm -v
9.4.0
```

nodeのバージョン19.6.1、npmのバージョン9.4.0です。

2週間位ずっと非常に困っています。
ご教示ください。
宜しくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

パッケージの指定時にバージョン番号は不要なのではないでしょうか。

```
$ npm uninstall openzeppelin-solidity
```

> ##### [Examples - npm-uninstall | npm Docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-uninstall#examples)
>
> ```
> npm uninstall sax
> ```

Comment: ありがとうございます！！解決しました！！
chatGPTにも聞いたりして2週間ほど足掻いていました。本当にありがとうございます。
（グローバルでインストールしていたパッケージ2つがあって、それについては、バージョン番号付きで2つとも上手くアンインストール出来ていましたので、釈然と致しませんが・・・）
npm listで表示されたパッケージ名をいつもそのままコピーアンドペーストしてアンインストールしようとしていました！
バージョン番号が要らないんですね！！
兎も角、上手くいきました！感謝致します。

Comment: [cubick](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/3060/cubick)さん、以前大変お世話になりました。
お見かけしたことがあると思い、これまでの質問を見ると、2度お世話になっておりました！！「DockerをWindowsで使う。フォルダーをアクセス権限を付けてマウントしたい。」（2021年12月8日）「apt コマンド実行時にネットワーク接続がタイムアウトしてしまう」（2021年12月10日）その節もご親切にありがとうございました！！